# C# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

Tags: c#, angular, cors, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm facing a problem with Cors with .Net Core 6. Although the Cors works with the previous version 3.1. I searched alot with no use.

The full error message is

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7230/api/teachers/subjectsByTeacher?teacherId=5&pageNo=1&pageSize=10&sorting=name%20asc' from origin 'https://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

Here is my program.cs class:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Configure cors.

string[] arrOrigins = { "https://localhost:3200", "http://localhost:3200" };

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(corsBuilder =>
        corsBuilder.WithOrigins(arrOrigins)
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader());
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.ConfigureDatabase(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddScopedServices();
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwaggerAndSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();// Use Cors.
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

// The backend method like this.

```
[Route("api/[Controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class TeachersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ITeacherAppService _teacherAppService;

    public TeachersController(ITeacherAppService teacherAppService)
    {
        _teacherAppService = teacherAppService;
    }

    [HttpGet("SubjectsByTeacher")]
    public async Task<PagedResultDto<TeachersGroupsSubjectDto>> GetSubjectsByTeacherAsync(
        [FromQuery] TeacherSearchParams searchParams)
    {
        return await _teacherAppService.GetSubjectsByTeacherAsync(searchParams);
    }
}

public class TeacherSearchParams
{
    [Required]
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public int PageNo { get; set; } = 1;
    public int PageSize { get; set; } = 10;
    public string Sorting { get; set; } = "id desc";
}
```

// The Angular method like this.

```
getSubjectsByTeacher(): Observable<IPagedResultDto<TeacherGroupSubject>> {

let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append("teacherId", "5");
params = params.append("pageNo", "1");
params = params.append("pageSize", "10");
params = params.append("sorting", "name asc");

const options = { params: params };

const fullUrl = `https://localhost:7230/api/teachers/subjectsByTeacher`;

return this.http.get<IPagedResultDto<TeacherGroupSubject>>(fullUrl, options)
  .pipe(map((response: IPagedResultDto<TeacherGroupSubject>) => {
    debugger;
    return response;
  }));
}
```

Any help would be appriated?

Comment: can you please cross check the variable [arrOrigins] with the error message may be there is a mismatch of the uri's @mohammed

Comment: Yes. I'm running the Angular project on port 3200.

Comment: try adding https://localhost:7230 this as well in that variable [arrOigins]

Comment: localhost:7230 is the web API service itself. Should be added?

Comment: Just in case, i would say and i would suggest to you use http in both the places unless https is enabled on both the places

Comment: I work on https for both. Angular project and the API project.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I got the solution. Add `.AllowCredentials()` method in the Cors configuration like this.

```
string[] arrOrigins = { "https://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4200" };

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(corsBuilder =>
        corsBuilder.WithOrigins(arrOrigins)
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowCredentials());// Add this line
});
```